Which datatype to use to delimit terrains and sub-parcels
I'm building a mobile app that allows users to define their terrain and its sub-parcels using PostGIS.
Initially, I planned to create a terrain table to store a polygon/multipolygon and a sub-parcel table to store individual polygons with a foreign key linking them to the terrain table. However, after some consideration, I realized this approach might not work well because sub-parcels often share common borders, which could potentially result in invalid polygons.
Here’s an example of a terrain with its sub-parcels for reference:

The "terrain polygon" represents the entire area (i.e., the outer boundary), and all other polygons within it are sub-parcels. Each sub-parcel is unique to one terrain polygon and shouldn’t (and cannot) belong to multiple terrain polygons.
So, which datatype should I use for this specific functionality? Should I use geometry or discard it and use geography because it's simpler(I'm not planning to map big areas)?

In response to answer by @GregStef
To clarify, the "terrain polygon" represents the entire area (i.e., the outer boundary), and all other polygons within it are sub-parcels. Each sub-parcel is unique to one terrain polygon and shouldn’t (and cannot) belong to multiple terrain polygons. I plan to enforce this restriction at the database level, possibly using functions like ST_DWithin—though I’ll need to research this approach further.
In terms of performance, would enforcing this constraint at the database level be less efficient than handling it at the application level?
Finally, could you clarify if this structure avoids any issues with polygon validity?
Specifically, is it acceptable for sub-parcels to share borders with other sub-parcels as well as with the main terrain polygon (or multipolygon)?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Design questions are often very subjective, which is not a good fit for our Focused question/Best answer model. Please [Edit] the Question so the image is embedded in the Question body, since following links violates best security practice.

You appear to have 3 accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience - please use these instructions to merge them: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Geometry has more features (and is more 'mature' IMO) I would definitely stick with geometry type (after all it's geometries you're manipulating), but there may be some changes needed in the overall design:

Since you are building the app, I think it would be prudent not to allow storing of invalid geometries (this can also be blocked in DB level) - it will save you --a lot-- of headaches down the road.
I do not understand the meaning of "because sub-parcels often share common borders, which could potentially result in invalid polygons" - it is very common for parcel polygons to be adjacent and that has no effect on their validity.
From your screenshot, one can assume that a sub-parcel may overlap more than one terrain polygons (even if this is due to end-user's negligence). If this is the case, you can also block the creation of such parcels (again, in your app, or in DB level). If you want to allow it, then you should either
a) use as FK the id of the terrain polygon which overlaps the biggest part of the parcel or b) use a separate table, holding the ID of a parcel and the IDs of each terrain polygons that overlap it (perhaps store the overlapping area, too)

EDIT AFTER EXPLANATION
This seems like an agricultural parcel approach - I'll give you the basic stuff, bottom-to-top (the app I'm taking the 'stuff' from, is something I've built and works since 2009):

You store your parcels in a db - you must guarantee their integrity, validity etc. Place as many constraints as you feel necessary to ensure this.

Make sure the geometries you store (I still recommend geometry) are valid - I cannot stress this point enough!

Terrain parcels are stored in the db before the users start to work AND they are read-only for the users

When your app sends a parcel to your db, depending on the capabilities of your app, you can check if the parcel is valid. Even if you cannot do that, when the parcel reaches the db, it will be rejected (by a constraint) if invalid.

Once a parcel is accepted in the db as valid, a trigger can calculate the intersection of the parcel with the terrain parcels. If the query returns exactly 1 row, it means that your parcel is 'properly' in a terrain and using the same query you can give it any attribute from 'its terrain'. If >1 rows are returned, it means that the parcel overlaps >1 terrain parcels and it's up to your trigger to do what you want - you can either reject it right away or judge to accept it, if, say there is one intersection 999.9999 sqm and any number of others < 0.0001.


As a final explanation: Your business logic is implemented in (5). (5) uses spatial manipulations -intersection and what not- so what you feed it with (BOTH terrain geoms and parcel geoms) must be valid polygons.
I think 'nuf said for now. If you have further Qs,let me know...

the original question has been updated in response to your answer

updated mu answer
